# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found : The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am getting error while trying to access service in spring framework.

[image: Spring MVC Application]

Controller class :-

```
package com.spring.mvc.tutorial;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World Again, from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Configuration class :-

```
package com.spring.mvc.tutorial;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring.mvc.tutorial")
public class HelloWorldConfiguration {

    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Initialization class :-

```
package com.spring.mvc.tutorial;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class HelloWorldInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ctx.register(HelloWorldConfiguration.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

View :-

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>HelloWorld page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE :-
Request : *http://localhost:8080/SpringMvcHelloWorld/*
This is developed in Eclipse Photon and deployed to Tomcat 8.5.

Comment: Is there any configuration that sets "SpringMvcHelloWorld" as your application's context root? Did you try to browse on localhost:8080 only ?

Comment: @Vitor Santos No to first and Yes to second. I am deploying it as a SpringMvcHelloWorld.war file.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting to the main html page in your controller class :

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello World from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "redirect:/main.html";
    }
```

Replace main.html with the path of your home page

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem and resolved it by checking where the attributes like @controller and @RequestMapping were binded to the mvc packages

**To check whether the sources are binded:**

Go to the controller page and ***press control and left button on @Controller together***.

1. If source is not binded then it will appear as shown in the figure. [image: link]
2. If the source is not binded then attach the source by clicking the attach source button and point towards the **spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE-sources**.
3. Check the other jars by following the above two steps.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet hence this is in form of an answer.

I had similar issue when tomcat was not initializing the web app. Can you please add as System.out.println on your initialiser to see if it is initializing the webapp in the first place.

And share your server logs on here.